# Django template can't loop defaultdict

Tags: python, django, loops

```
import collections

data = [
  {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith'}, 
  {'firstname': 'Samantha', 'lastname': 'Smith'}, 
  {'firstname': 'shawn', 'lastname': 'Spencer'}, 
]

new_data = collections.defaultdict(list)

for d in data:
    new_data[d['lastname']].append(d['firstname'])

print new_data
```

Here's the output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Smith': ['John', 'Samantha'], 'Spencer': ['shawn']})
```

and here's the template:

```
{% for lastname, firstname in data.items %}
  <h1> {{ lastname }} </h1>
  <p> {{ firstname|join:", " }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

But the loop in my template doesn't work. Nothing shows up. It doesn't even give me an error. How can i fix this? It's supposed to show the lastname along with the firstname, something like this:

```
<h1> Smith </h1>
<p> John, Samantha </p>

<h1> Spencer </h1>
<p> shawn </p>
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code that puts the dictionary into the context for the template.  Are you sure that's happening properly?

Comment: Yes, everything else renders correctly outside of the loop.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

try:

```
dict(new_data)
```

and in Python 2 it is better to use `iteritems` instead of `items` :)

Comment: I can't believe something simple like that worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It was actually filed as a bug against django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335 but turned out the only good solution was indeed to transform it to a dict, as it's now shown in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) and it's visible in the [changeset](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335)

Answer (score 108):

You can avoid the copy to a new dict by disabling the defaulting feature of *defaultdict* once you are done inserting new values:

```
new_data.default_factory = None
```

**Explanation**

The [template variable resolution algorithm in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) will attempt to resolve `new_data.items` as `new_data['items']` first, which resolves to an empty list when using *defaultdict(list)*.

To disable the defaulting to an empty list and have Django fail on `new_data['items']` then continue the resolution attempts until calling `new_data.items()`, the [default_factory attribute of *defaultdict*](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__) can be set to *None*.

Comment: +1 - This is much more efficient than the selected answer, especially with a large dictionary set.

Comment: Great answer, explanation helped a lot understanding the underlaying problem!

Comment: I might add that a {% for k, v in detauldictvar %} allows you to iterate on the defaultdict's element even without setting the default_factory to None.With Sebastien explanation now I can understand why :-)

Answer (score 8):

Since the "problem" still exist years later and is inherint to the way Django templates work, I prefer writing a new answer giving the full details of why this behaviour is kept as-is.

#### How-to fix the bug

First, the solution is to cast the `defaultdict` into a `dict` before passing it to the template context:

```py
context = {
    'data': dict(new_data)
}
```

You should not use `defaultdict` objects in template context in Django.

#### But why?

The reason behind this "bug" is detailed in the following [Django issue #16335](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335):

> Indeed, it boils down to the fact that the template language uses the same syntax for dictionary and attribute lookups.

... and from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/#variables):

> Dictionary lookup, attribute lookup and list-index lookups are implemented with a dot notation. [...] If a variable resolves to a callable, the template system will call it with no arguments and use its result instead of the callable.

When Django resolve your template expression **it will try first `data['items']`**. BUT, this is a valid expression, which will automatically creates a new entry `items` in your defaultdict `data`, initialized with an empty list (in the original author case) and returns the list created (empty).

The intented action would be to call the method `items` with no arguments of the instance `data` (in short: `data.items()`), but since `data['items']` was a valid expression, Django stop there and gets the empty list just created.

If you try the same code but with `data = defaultdict(int)`, you would get a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, because Django won't be able to iterate over the "0" value returned by the creation of the new entry of the `defaultdict`.