# Looping problem with dictionary in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm not sure why this template is not rendering anything to the page.
Is there anything obvious I am missing here?

View:

```
@user_passes_test(is_staff)
def details_activity_log(request, project_id, template='projects/details_activity_log.html'):

    project = get_object_or_404(Project.objects.select_related(), pk=project_id)
    action_log = project.projectactionlog_set.all()

    log_group = defaultdict(list)

    for log in action_log:
        log_group[log.action_time.strftime('%y%m%d')].append(log)


    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    return render_to_response(template, {
        'log_group'  : log_group,
        'project'    : project,
        'action_log' : action_log,
        'tab_5'      : 'active',
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

log_group contains a *dict* of model objects like so:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'110614': [<ProjectActionLog: ProjectActionLog object>, ...]})
```

Template:

```
   {% for key, log in log_group %}
      {% for action in log %}
        {{ action }}
        {{ action.action_time }}                    
        {{ action.user.first_name }}
        {{ action.message }}
        {{ action.object_name }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**Edit**
If only I had looked in the docs I would have seen the answer. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for

However it's a tricky situation since the templates don't throw any runtime errors when the loop can't unpack the iterator items.

Comment: You are using a `defaultdict`, careful! See my answer below or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764110/django-template-cant-loop-defaultdict

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
{% for key, log in log_group %}
```

to

```
{% for key, log in log_group.items %}
```

Comment: Even better:  `log_group.iteritems`.  But in this case it doesn't look like he is using `key` so `itervalues` should do.

Comment: Could you please explain why this is? From a bit of searching I gather that iteritems is a generator, and lazy load the items taking up less RAM? Is that correct?

Comment: He's correct using the iter* methods is generally better.  The side effect is that you if you needed to loop over the dict more than once you're usually better off just loading it into memory (unless it's huge).  If your dict is reasonably small the difference between the two is pretty negligible on an individual basis.

Answer (score 4):

Update your for loop to:

```
{% for log in log_group.itervalues %}
```

Or, if you actually need `key` (your example template doesn't show you using it):

```
{% for key, log in log_group.iteritems %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also be **very** careful with `defaultdicts` in a django template, and I see in your code that you are indeed using a `defaultdict`.

They plainly don't work as expected inside a template because of the way django attempts to access properties/attributes/etc. and the only solution is to convert them to dicts:

```
context['dictstructure'] = dict(mydefaultdict)
```

The [template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) was patched following [ticket #16335](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335), [changeset](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335) to include a special notice on this issue.

> Technically, when the template system encounters a
>   dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute lookup
> - Method call
> - List-index lookup
>
> This can cause some unexpected behavior with objects that override
>   dictionary lookup. For example, consider the following code snippet
>   that attempts to loop over a collections.defaultdict:
>
> ```
> {% for k, v in defaultdict.iteritems %}
>     Do something with k and v here... 
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> Because dictionary lookup happens first, that behavior kicks in and provides a default
>   value instead of using the intended .iteritems() method. In this case,
>   consider converting to a dictionary first.

Please also see question [Django template can't loop defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764110/django-template-cant-loop-defaultdict)