# Django Dict of List Template

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am trying to print out some stuff from a dictionary of lists in django.
Here is my `dict_`:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'UIT ENERGY PRODUCERS CLASS': [6, 3, '08-18-2017'], 'EQUITY GROWTH CLASS': [18, 3, '08-18-2017'], 'UNCONSTRAINED BOND CLASS': [13, 3, '08-18-2017']})
```

In my views.py:

```
context['obj_items'] = dict_
return context
```

Then in my templates.html:

```
    {% for key, value_list  in obj_items.items %}
        {% for value in value_list %}
            {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But nothing is getting printed out. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your view is returning the right context? Do you use `render` ?

Comment: yup if I do {{ obj_items }}, the defaultdict appears with all the data

Comment: Well, then try to cast `dict_` to a `dict`, like this: `context['obj_items'] = dict(dict_)`

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705669/my-defaultdictlist-wont-show-up-on-template-but-does-in-my-view/10705819#10705819

Comment: Oh wait, i changed it from iteritems to items and now it worked :) Thanks

Comment: `iteritems` will work in Python 2, but in Python 3 you should use `items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
dict(dict_)
```

django template doesn't accept defaultdict