# django template loop collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my view I create the following dictionary of lists from a queryset

```
#view.py
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(owner=user, dashboard=tab).order_by('position')
my_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))    
for obj in queryset:
    my_dict[int(obj.position.split('-')[0])][int(obj.position.split('-')[2])].append(obj)
return Response({'queryset': dict(my_dict)}, template_name='dashboard/_maps_tab.html')
```

Position field is a charFiled following the format: X-X-X-X used the create the my_dict

my_dict is

```
--[1] #group
----[1] #col 1
------ object1.1.1 #group.col.pk
------ object1.1.2
------ object1.1.3
----[2] #col 2
------ object1.2.4
----[3] #col3
------ object1.3.5
------ object1.3.6

--[2] #group
----[1] #col 1
------object2.1.7 #group.col.pk

--[3] #group
----[1] #col1
------ object3.1.8 #group.col.pk
----[2] #col2
------object3.2.9
------object3.2.10
```

In my template I would like to do

```
{% for groups in queryset.iteritems %}

    groups = {{ groups }} <br>

    {% for cols in groups %}

      cols = {{ cols }} <br>

      {% for objs in cols %}

        {{ objs }} in <br><br>

        {% for obj in objs %}        
          {{ obj.title }}, 
          {{ obj.desc}}, 
          {{ obj.fieldN }},         

        {% endfor %}

      {% endfor %}


    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

The result is

```
groups = (1, defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [<Obj: Obj 1 by daviddd>, <Obj: Obj 2 by daviddd>, <Obj: Obj3 by daviddd>], 2: [<Obj: Obj 4 by daviddd>], 3: [<Obj: Obj 5 by daviddd>, <Obj: Obj 6 by daviddd>, <Obj: Obj 7 by daviddd>]}))
cols = 1
cols = defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [<Obj: Obj 1 by daviddd>, <Obj: Obj 2 by daviddd>, <Obj: Obj3 by daviddd>], 2: [<Obj: Obj 4 by daviddd>], 3: [<Obj: Obj 5 by daviddd>, <Obj: Obj 6 by daviddd>, <Obj: Obj 7 by daviddd>]})

groups = (2, defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [<Obj: Obj 7.7 by daviddd>]}))
cols = 2
cols = defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [<Obj: Obj 7.7 by daviddd>]})

groups = (3, defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [<Obj: Obj 7.8 by daviddd>]}))
cols = 3
cols = defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [<Obj: Obj 7.8 by daviddd>]})
```

I tried to do `{% for cols in groups.1 %}` but it's not working (empty).
If I do {% for cols in groups.iteritems %} I have: "Int is not iterable".

Looking at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335 my case is

```
my_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))    
dictionary['foo']['foo1'].append('bar')
```

How can I solve?

Thanks in advance!

D

Comment: Use [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/)

Comment: I never used django-mptt for this purpose, good to know. I have to keep the dict structure, because it will load a complex HTML/jQuery page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view.py solution was:

```
    my_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))

    for obj in queryset:
        my_dict[int(obj.position.split('-')[0])][int(obj.position.split('-')[2])].append(obj)

    for obj in my_dict:            
        my_dict[obj].default_factory = None

    return Response({'queryset': dict(my_dict)}, template_name='_internal_template.html')
```

Linked to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335 and 
[Django template can't loop defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764110/django-template-cant-loop-defaultdict)

My template

```
{% for groups in queryset.itervalues  %}

    groups = {{ groups }}    
    <br><br>

    {% for cols in groups.itervalues  %}

      cols = {{ cols }}    
      <br><br>

      {% for obj in cols  %}

        obj = {{ obj}} in <br><br>
        obj info = {{ obj.title }}, {{ obj.abstract }}<br>

      {% endfor %}      

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```