# Weird runtime error when looping over DefaultDict in django template

Tags: python, django

**Using Django 1.5.1**

I have a simple code here -

```
count_by_media_type = defaultdict(int)
for user_media in user_media_data:
    count_by_media_type[user_media['media_type']] += 1
```

This is a part of a view, which is rendered in the template using a for iteration loop -

```
{% for media_type in count_by_media_type %}
    ..........
{% endfor %}
```

The value of  `count_by_media_type` just before the `render_to_response` method in the loop is 
`defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'photo': 1, u'audio': 4, u'video': 3})`

But somehow, on rendering , there is a runtime error in iteration

`dictionary changed size during iteration`

And the value of `count_by_media_type` as seen in the template context becomes

`defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'photo': 1, u'audio': 4, u'video': 3, u'media_type': 0})`

This is quite weird, as how does a new key `media_type` is coming in the variable?

Now , when I switch the above code, mentioned in the view with

`count_by_media_type = Counter([user_media['media_type'] for user_media in user_media_data])`

Everything works fine.

Any clues anyone?

Comment: I'd guess that in the for loop you are accessing directly or indirectly to `count_by_media_type.get('media_type')`, and so the `defaultdict` gets modified.

Comment: Ahh. you are correct. I am accessing the value by {{count_by_media_type.media_type}}. I didnt realize this. 
Thanks, I am relieved :)

Comment: As an aside, you might find it easier to loop over the items instead of the keys: `{% for media_type, count in count_by_media_type.iteritems %}{{ count }}{% endfor %}`. You'll still have to use one of the fixes in my answer below.

Comment: Yes @Alasdair, Making it a dict will definitely do it. However, I went ahead with Counter Collection. Thanks a lot to you as well for your answer.
Django Docs are really good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `defaultdict`s causes weird behaviour in Django templates, because of the way template variable lookups work. See the *Behind the scenes* box of the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#variables).

The Django docs suggest converting the `defaultdict` to a regular `dict` before passing to the template.

```
count_by_media_type = defaultdict(int)
for user_media in user_media_data:
    count_by_media_type[user_media['media_type']] += 1

count_by_media_type = dict(count_by_media_type)
```

Or, [as this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842716/113962), you can disable the defaulting feature after you have finished inserting values.

```
count_by_media_type.default_factory = None
```

Comment: @HåkenLid yes, and as a result of that ticket they have now [documented the behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#variables).