# Unable to render dictionary values in Django templates

Tags: django, templates, tagging

I have a dictionary  that is returned by one of the Django view.

I am running the below code in Django templates.

```
       {% for i in d.values %}
              {{ i }}
       {% endfor %}
```

Output returns nothing. But if I run,

```
       {% for i in d %}
              {{ i }}

       {% endfor %}
```

I am able to get keys.

Please let me know why I am not able to print dictionary values

Comment: Is `d` the dictionary? What are the values in the dictionary? Are you sure it is not a `set` (these have similar notation).

Comment: Perhaps `d` is a `defaultdict` - in that case, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764110/django-template-cant-loop-defaultdict) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
   {% for i,j in d.items %}
          {{ i }} {{ j }}
   {% endfor %}
```

use this to get the `key in i and value in j`